# Please help me understand the jump in used space in a freshly formatted disk

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space

Let me try to explain what I am trying to understand.

I have 2 physical drives in my laptop.

The one without the OS, the D drive, shows 200 MB of used space right after formatting. (Right click -> Properties)

It shows a protected operating system file 'System Information Volume'. It shows 0 bytes of both size and size on disk. (Right click -> Properties)

Now after sometime, another protected operating system file appears, '$Recycle.Bin'. It show a size on disk of 120 bytes, and size of 0 bytes. (Right click -> Properties)

And after '$Recycle.Bin' appears the drive shows a used space of 1.3 GB (Right click -> Properties).

The recovery points on D drive are disabled.

Can someone please answer the following questions-
1) What do you think causes the jump in the used space?
2) The original 200 MB of used space right after formatting, is that normal?

Thank you.

Comment: Did the drive use a different filesystem before? Newer files systems have features like journaling that require space is set aside for them. Even newer versions of the same file system may have features the prior versions either lacked or had disabled by default.

Comment: Nope, the drive was using NTFS before as well. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: 2) Formatting to NTFS  filesystem creates a lot of disk structures. They are stored in metafiles, which are hidden files needed some space to be stored in. 200 Mb is normal. 1) The disk space for metafiles can be reserved, but not occupied. If so non-occupied reserved space is calculated as in the free pool.

Comment: I was actually thinking about NTFS when i mentioned new features. Recent versions of NTFS add journaling. But that's just guessing. You can use something like [sysinternals diskview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/diskview) to actually view the layout of the data on the physical drive.